# Getting org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: Checked exception is invalid for this method! Even though I am throwing correct exception

Tags: mockito, junit4

Getting org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException:
Checked exception is invalid for this method! Even though I am throwing correct exception. I am trying to test this class DecileConfigurationJsonConverter. In the test I am testing the exception throw scene while reading DB data. Its throws IOException if it cant read DB data and in the mock I did throw the exact same Exception yet I got the above error.

```
  public class DecileConfigurationJsonConverter  implement               AttributeConverter<List<DecileParameter>,String>{
  private static final  ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
  @Override
  public List<DecileParameter> convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
      if(dbData==null)
          return null;
      List<DecileParameter> dep = null;
      try
      {
          dep = objectMapper.readValue(dbData,
                  new TypeReference<List<DecileParameter>>() {});
      }
      catch (final IOException e)
      {
          return null;
      }
      return dep;
  }
}

  @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
  @SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
  @AutoConfigureMockMvc
  @ActiveProfiles("dev-test")
  @TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-dev-test.yml")
  @FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
  public class UtilPackageTestMore {

  @Mock
  ObjectMapper objectMapper;

  private static void setFinalStaticField(Class<?> clazz, String fieldName, Object value)
          throws ReflectiveOperationException {

      Field field = clazz.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
      field.setAccessible(true);

      Field modifiers = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
      modifiers.setAccessible(true);
      modifiers.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);

      field.set(null, value);
  }

  @Test
  public void TestDecileConfigurationJsonConverterExceptions() throws Exception
  {
      DecileConfigurationJsonConverter dc= new DecileConfigurationJsonConverter();
      ObjectMapper objecmapper = Mockito.mock(ObjectMapper.class);
      setFinalStaticField(DecileConfigurationJsonConverter.class, "objectMapper", objecmapper);

      List<DecileParameter> attribute = new ArrayList<>();
      attribute.add(new DecileParameter("1","2","3","4","5"));
      Mockito.when(objecmapper.writeValueAsString(attribute)).thenThrow(JsonProcessingException.class);
      String res = dc.convertToDatabaseColumn(attribute);
      assertNull(res);

      //here is the exception got thrown
      Mockito.when(objecmapper.readValue("db data",new TypeReference<List<DecileParameter>>() {})).thenThrow(java.io.IOException.class);
      List<DecileParameter> convertToEntityAttribute = dc.convertToEntityAttribute("db data");
      assertNull(convertToEntityAttribute);

  }
```

Comment: Make sure to check out my updated answer. Nothing at all needs to be mocked for this scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must throw an `Exception`, but you are throwing a `Class<Exception>`. `JsonProcessingException.class` returns a `Class<Exception>` instance. `new JsonProcessingException()` returns a new `Exception` instance. You can only throw the latter.

```
Mockito.when(objecmapper.writeValueAsString(attribute))
        .thenThrow(new JsonProcessingException());
```

But in fact you don't need to mock anything at all here. Try to avoid Reflection. Keep your tests simple and don't couple them to your implementation.

```
public class DecileConfigurationJsonConverter
    implements AttributeConverter<List<DecileParameter>, String> {
  private static final ObjectMapper OBJECT_MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();

  @Override
  public List<DecileParameter> convertToEntityAttribute(final String dbData) {
      if (dbData==null) return null;
      try
      {
          return OBJECT_MAPPER.readValue(dbData,
                  new TypeReference<List<DecileParameter>>() {});
      }
      catch (final IOException e)
      {
          return null;
      }
  }
}

public class UtilPackageTestMore {

  @Test
  public void TestDecileConfigurationJsonConverterExceptions() throws Exception
  {
      final DecileConfigurationJsonConverter dc = new DecileConfigurationJsonConverter();

      final List<DecileParameter> convertToEntityAttribute = dc.convertToEntityAttribute("INVALID_JSON"); // value can be anything that cannot be deserialized
      assertNull(convertToEntityAttribute);

  }
}
```